# Show cart items after login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working in wordpress.I want whenever without login if i added some items in cart then after login will redirect to cart page.How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user is logged in and the current page is cart page. For that use the following hook as explained below.

```
function check_user_logged_in(){

   global $woocommerce;
   if ( is_user_logged_in() && !empty(WC()->cart->get_cart())) {

    wp_redirect( home_url().'/cart' );

    exit();
    }
}
add_action('init','check_user_logged_in');
```

Comment: not working,I want if right now i am not login and i added 2 items in cart , because i disable check for guest users and then login with my credentials then page should redirect to cart pages for proceed to checkout.

Comment: I updated my code and tested in my local as well. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code for redirect in woo commerce after user login:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

function wc_login_redirect($redirect_to) {

    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    if (count($items) > 0) {
        $redirect_to = site_url() . '/' . CART-PAGE-URL/SLUG . '/';
    } else if ($fromFooter == 'true') {
        $redirect_to = site_url() . '/' . MY-ACCOUNT-URL/SLUG . '';
    } else {
        $redirect_to = site_url();
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```